# Null sets as unions of countable sets

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a collection of countable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ and let $Z:=\bigcup\mathcal{C}$ be the union of its members.

For which (uncountable) $\mathcal{C}$ does $Z$ have Lebesgue measure zero?

Comment: For instance, if the elements of $\mathcal C$ are the singletons of the Cantor set?

Comment: That's of course nowhere near necessary. By "which" I mean an "ifandonlyif" condition.

Comment: I don't think that condition "$\bigcup\mathcal C$ has Lebesgue measure zero" can be replaced by any condition on $\mathcal C$ that is essentially different.

Comment: @DamianReding Arthur's condition is not as far from necessary as you make it sound: if $Z$ has positive upper measure then there must also exist a choice of singletons, one from each set in $C$, such that those singletons form an uncountable set of positive upper measure.

Comment: Isn't the question equivalent to "which uncountable sets $Z$ have measure zero?"  Ponder that if you must.